# How is AsQueryable() implemented in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I see that this extension method is

```
/// <summary>
/// Converts a generic <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1"/> to a generic <see cref="T:System.Linq.IQueryable`1"/>.
/// </summary>
/// 
/// <returns>
/// An <see cref="T:System.Linq.IQueryable`1"/> that represents the input sequence.
/// </returns>
/// <param name="source">A sequence to convert.</param><typeparam name="TElement">The type of the elements of <paramref name="source"/>.</typeparam><exception cref="T:System.ArgumentNullException"><paramref name="source"/> is null.</exception>
public static IQueryable<TElement> AsQueryable<TElement>(this IEnumerable<TElement> source)
{
  return (IQueryable<TElement>) null;
}
```

But I don't understand what the return is doing, just returning null isn't it?

Comment: Can you explain how you obtained this source and why you think this could work?

Comment: Where did you find this? And what does this have to do with ASP.NET?

Comment: I just see this using dotpeek (first time I use it though), regarding the asp.net tag was my bad, sorry

Comment: That shouldn't happen. How did you find this? You can also try with JustDecompile.

Comment: Thanks. I just open the dll I have in my folder with dotPeel and there I wen to system.Linq.Querayable. As I said it's the first time I use this tool

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ReSharper gives me the following:

```
/// <summary>
/// Converts a generic <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1"/> to a generic <see cref="T:System.Linq.IQueryable`1"/>.
/// </summary>
/// 
/// <returns>
/// An <see cref="T:System.Linq.IQueryable`1"/> that represents the input sequence.
/// </returns>
/// <param name="source">A sequence to convert.</param><typeparam name="TElement">The type of the elements of <paramref name="source"/>.</typeparam><exception cref="T:System.ArgumentNullException"><paramref name="source"/> is null.</exception>
[__DynamicallyInvokable]
public static IQueryable<TElement> AsQueryable<TElement>(this IEnumerable<TElement> source)
{
  if (source == null)
    throw System.Linq.Error.ArgumentNull("source");
  if (source is IQueryable<TElement>)
    return (IQueryable<TElement>) source;
  else
    return (IQueryable<TElement>) new EnumerableQuery<TElement>(source);
}
```

The standard outlining algorithm of VS just works that way. VS doesn't give you the real implementation details.

Comment: Ok, sorry then for the silly question. I didn't know how to look for the code properly. Thanks both

Answer (score 1):

I don't think what you're looking at is the final or full version of the code. Reflector gave me this (nearly identical to timmkrause's answer) for .NET 3.5:

```
public static IQueryable<TElement> AsQueryable<TElement>(this IEnumerable<TElement> source)
{
    if (source == null)
    {
        throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
    }
    if (source is IQueryable<TElement>)
    {
        return (IQueryable<TElement>) source;
    }
    return new EnumerableQuery<TElement>(source);
}
```

You need to use a disassembler to get from the compiled CLR assembly code back to a source implementation; metadata providers such as the one built into Visual Studio 2012 or similar don't normally give you the actual source.

Note that Resharper and Reflector came up with different styles and naming qualifications, but each shows identical functionality.